# Left invariant vector field on $S^1$

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

Is there an explicit example of a left-invariant (unit)vector field associated with the Lie group $S^1$ (1-sphere)? That is, I am looking for a vector field  $X:S^1\to\mathbb{R}^2$.

Moreover, is there an example of a left-invariant (unit)vector-field $Y:S^3\to\mathbb{R}^4$ associated with the Lie group $S^3$?

Remark: From the theory of Lie-groups it is known that such vector-field do exist on $S^1$ and $S^3$.

Comment: You get any LIVF by taking a tangent vector and applying each element of the group.  For $S^1$, what happens when you rotate a vector through every possible angle?

Comment: Think of $S^1 \subset R^2$. Start with one tangent vector at one point. Then as you move along the circle, simply slide the vector along, without changing its length or direction. For $S^3$ I remember using quaternions to come up with specific vector fields. Wait a min! Why not use complex numbers in $S^1$ case? At point $e^{it}$ the vector $e^{i(t+\pi /2)}$ is tangent to the circle.

Answer (score 3):

Let's compute the left-invariant vector fields as I would do it for an arbitrary Lie group $\mathsf{G}$. Let $g : \mathsf{G} \to GL(n)$ be a matrix-valued embedding into $GL(n)$ for some $n$. In particular, for our case we have $\mathsf{G} = U(1)$, and $n=1$. Note that this group is abelian. Then we can compute the left-invariant Maurer-Cartan forms for the group by $$g^{-1} \textrm{d} g = \lambda^a T_a$$
where $T_a$ is a chosen basis for the Lie algebra. The $\lambda^a$ form a global coframe for $\mathsf{G}$, and this is dual to the frame of left-invariant vector fields. So once we work out the $\lambda^a$, we can work out the dual vector fields, and then we are done.

To that end, let us choose an embedding $g = e^{i\theta}$ of our group in $U(1)$, and fix a basis $T_a = \{i\}$ of the Lie algebra for $\mathsf{G}$. Then the calculation simply becomes $$g^{-1} \textrm{d} g = e^{-i\theta} i e^{i \theta} \textrm{d} \theta = i \textrm{d} \theta$$
We conclude that the Maurer-Cartan frame is given by $$\lambda^1 = \textrm{d} \theta$$
The dual vector field(s) to this is easy to obtain:
$$v_1 = \partial_{\theta} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$$